# Mercury: How to declare determinism of a higher-order data type?

Tags: lambda, non-deterministic, mercury

When I compile the Mercury code below, I get this error from the compiler:

```
In clause for `main(di, uo)':
  in argument 1 of call to predicate
  `test_with_anonymous_functions.assert_equals'/5:
  mode error: variable `V_15' has
  instantiatedness `/* unique */((func) =
  (free >> ground) is semidet)',
  expected instantiatedness was `((func) =
  (free >> ground) is det)'.
```

I think what the compiler is saying is "When you declared the type `test_case`, you didn't specify a determinism, so I assumed you meant `det`. But then you passed in a `semidet` lambda."

My questions:

- What's the syntax for declaring the determinism of a type? The guesses I've tried have all resulted in syntax errors.
- Can someone explain what the `/* unique */` part of `TestCase`'s instantiatedness means? Will that cause a mismatch, between the given & expected instantiatedness?
- Is there a less verbose way of declaring the lambda in `main`? I have as much declaration about the lambda as I do code inside the lambda.

The code:

```
% (Boilerplate statements at the top are omitted.)

% Return the nth item of a list
:- func nth(list(T), int) = T.
:- mode nth(in,      in)  = out is semidet.
nth([Hd | Tl], N) = (if N = 0 then Hd else nth(Tl, N - 1)).

% Unit testing: Execute TestCase to get the 
% actual value. Print a message if (a) the lambda fails
% or (b) the actual value isn't the expected value.
:- type test_case(T) == ((func) = T).
:- pred assert_equals(test_case(T), T,  string, io.state, io.state).
:- mode assert_equals(in,           in, in,     di,       uo) is det.
assert_equals(TestCase, Expected, Message, !IO) :-
    if   Actual = apply(TestCase), Actual = Expected
    then true % test passed. do nothing.
    else io.format("Fail:\t%s\n", [s(Message)], !IO).

main(!IO) :-
    List = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    assert_equals( ((func) = (nth(List, 0)::out) is semidet),
                 1, "Nth", !IO).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me a while to get the hang of as well.

The problem is that the mode of a higher-order term is **not** part of its type. So there is no syntax for declaring the determinism of a type. The determinism of a higher-order term is carried in the mode.

In your example, the first argument of `assert_equals` has type `test_case(T)`, but has mode `in`. This means that the fact that the function is `semidet` gets lost. I'm not sure if it would actually compile or run correctly if the function you're passing was `det`; even in that case the mode really shouldn't be `in`.

Here's an example:

```
:- pred apply_transformer(func(T) = T, T, T).
:- mode apply_transformer(func(in) = out is det, in, out).
apply_transformer(F, X0, X) :-
    X = F(X0).

main(!IO) :-
    apply_transformer((func(S0) = S is det :- S = "Hello " ++ S0),
                      "World", Msg),
    print(Msg, !IO),
    nl(!IO).
```

As you can see, the type of the first argument to `apply_transformer` only says that it is a higher-order function takes one argument and returns a result of the same type. It's the mode declaration that actually says the function parameter has mode `in` and the function result has mode `out`, and that its determinism is `det`.

I believe the `/*unique */` bit of the error message says that the compiler thinks it is a unique value. I'm not sure whether that's a problem or not, since you're not using unique modes anywhere other than the usual `io` state.

As for the lambda syntax, I don't think you can do any better unfortunately. I find the syntax of lambdas in Mercury to be fairly unsatisfactory; they're so verbose that I usually end up just making named functions/predicates instead for all but the most trivial lambdas.

---

---

Comment: Thanks, Ben. That explanation makes sense (and it fixed my problem!)

Comment: @Evan: I forgot to add to my answer, it's also possible to create mode aliases for complex modes of higher-order terms. I did that once for a module with dozens of predicates taking higher-order arguments of the same type; I declared a type and a mode up the top of the module and just used those throughout.

Comment: @Evan: hey, would you like to have a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896296/creating-a-deterministic-finite-automata-dfa-mercury

-- nothing to do with this post, just for attract attention to Evan

Answer (score 4):

Ben is right,

I'd like to add that Mercury assumes that functions are deterministic by default (it's sensible that functions ought to be deterministic).  This is not true for predicates in which the determinism must be declared.  This makes it easier to do higher order programming with deterministic functions than any other function or predicate, simply because there's less boilerplate.

Because of this, you are able to make your lambda expression a little bit more concise.  You can also move the body of the lambda expression into the head by substituting the variable S in the head with the body.

```
apply_transformer((func(S0) = "Hello " ++ S0),
                  "World", Msg),
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second question, the `/* unique */` in the error message is referring to the first argument of the call to `assert_equals`, which is the lambda term you have just constructed. This is the only place the term is used, hence the reference to it is unique at the point of call.

A unique inst matches a ground inst (but not vice-versa), so in this case the uniqueness will not cause a mismatch. It's the determinism that is the problem.